# Mp3 player and JMF

Tags: java, swing, mp3, javasound

I am trying to develop a mp3 player using java.I tried several codes and it ended up in too many errors.So please provide me hints about the code and also help me to configure JMF??

Comment: See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for details on how to play MP3.

Answer (score 1):

JMF natively does not support mp3 as mp3 is not open source.

If you want to play mp3 file you may do this using jlayer, mp3spi and tritonus libraries.

If you need more informations on these library then let me know.

Please see the below code. With the three libraries added to built path, this code worked for me. Hope this will help you

```
String mp3File = "path to mp3 file";

public void playMp3(String mp3File ) {
    AudioInputStream din = null;
    AudioInputStream in = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(mp3File);
        in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
        din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
        line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        if (line != null) {
            line.open(decodedFormat);
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            // Start
            line.start();

            int nBytesRead;
            while ((nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
                if (flag) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            line.drain();
            line.stop();
            line.close();
            din.close();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, uafe.getMessage());
        logger.error(uafe);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lue.getMessage());
        logger.error(lue);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.getMessage());
        logger.error(ioe);
    } finally {
        if (din != null) {
            try {
                din.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: *"JMF natively does not support mp3.."* That is 'just plain wrong'. It comes standard with an MP3 SPI, as detailed in the Java Sound info. page linked in my 1st comment (above).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson while working on a project to split mp3 files I have found this from oracles site. So I do not see any wrong here.  U can check it here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html and here also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/sound.html . To play mp3 in JMF you need to install mp3 plugin separately.